# Prevent gcloud public bucket from listing all objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, acl

I have a bucket `<my-bucket>` in google cloud storage. It has public access and serves all assets and static files for our website. All works fine. But I don't like that on the url `https://storage.googleapis.com/<my-bucket>` it shows the document tree with all the objects in the bucket.
How can I prevent it? I tried putting index.html file to the bucket root it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to apply the "Cloud Storage Legacy - Storage Legacy Object Reader" role instead of "Cloud Storage - Storage Object Viewer" for allUsers, since the former does not include permissions to list objects in a bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets

Comment: Great! I wonder though what Google's reason for making this 'Legacy' is? Seems to me the use case of having all objects in a bucket public, without listing permission, is a very common one. I'm a bit concerned a legacy rule will move to deprecated eventually...

Comment: @jola I believe it's just a naming thing. I remember reading a comment here where someone said "Legacy" in this case just means first generation (pre-IAM), compared to the newer fine-grained IAM roles. These legacy roles have been around for years now and I haven't seen any news of them going away.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is to use the legacy "Storage Legacy Object Reader" Permission which only allows "storage.objects.get":
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

Personally I do not like using the Legacy rules so I created my own rule for this: IAM & Admin -> Roles -> + Create role
And I only gave it the objects get permission:
[image]

Then in the bucket permissions I assigned that rule to "allUsers":
[image]

Also if you have multiple public buckets using this method you can later change the permissions for that rule in one place